# Keyboard slideout causes UIWebView to shift left

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

My app is powered by a full screen `UIWebView`. It works well except when the keyboard is brought up the view is shifted over about 10 pixels leaving a white gap (see screenshot below).

Does anyone know what causes this and if there are any solutions or work arounds?

UPDATE:
To be more specific, the `UIWebView` is not shifting over, the HTML content is shifting over.

[image]

Comment: I also noticed that the space will appear if I doubletap the screen.

Comment: Is the UIWebView shifted or its content? Can you should some code for how you create the UIWebView and add it to the screen?

Comment: it also appears after double tap? then it has something to do with the zooming. The keyboard have this behavior too: when you focus on a textfield the web page get zoomed to show the appropriate resolution. Look for some code to disable the webpage zoom. eg. `scalesPageToFit`

Comment: Ryan, the UIWebView's content is what is shifting.

Comment: relikd, I tried the following but issues still happens: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;user-scalable=0;"></meta>

Comment: Could you please give exact HTML which you display there?

Comment: I assume you are trying to load content configured similar to mobile websites (basically m.xxxxx.com something like that), in that case I don't see any reason for this space to appear. As suggested by others, if possible post your html content so that we can help.

Answer (score 8):

You can try disabling zoom for webview:

```
webview.scrollView.delegate = self;

-(UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {
return nil;
}
```

Comment: A lot of answers to this question talk about resetting the bounds of the scrollview after the keyboard appears. That's ugly and creates some weird bouncing in an app. This solution is the very best way to keep the web view from shifting around in the first place.